# getting user information from google account in android

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I am trying to get user information from google account.
I am referring to [this doc](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people) . I am facing problem in importing `import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;`

But it showing error `The method getCurrentPerson() is undefined for the type PlusClient`

**Code**

```
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
        .setActions("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
        .build();
}
..........................................
```

For getting user data code I have used

```
Person currentPerson = mPlusClient.getCurrentPerson();
disp_name = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
disp_url = currentPerson.getUrl();
disp_id = currentPerson.getId();
name.setText(disp_name);
url.setText(disp_url);
id.setText(disp_id);
```

In manifest.xml file also I have encounter an error showing

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/
 google_play_services_version')
```

in the following line

```
<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Do I have to enter `google_play_services_version` manually ?

Comment: how did you initialize the PlusClient mPlusClient? Post the initialization code please

Comment: `mPlusClient = new PlusClient(this, this, this, Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE);`

Comment: @StarsSky It also showing `com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person can not be resolved`

Comment: maybe this guide is usefull https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_4_initialize_the_plusclient

Comment: @StarsSky But I wanna ask, is `Person` class deprecated ? Because I have problem importing that.

Comment: Which version of the Google Play services SDK are you using?

Comment: Could you paste more of the code of the activity, e.g. where you construct the PlusClient? The code looks right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that the meta tag is not working, i would say that Google Play Services is not being linked in properly.

Make sure you've added play services as an Android library project - check each of the steps on https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_2_configure_your_eclipse_project

Comment: Actually problem was in my `Google Play Services`. I updated it recently but dont know why it was showing that error. So I update it again and it's working now.Thanx